# What is conceptually happening in this modulation function?

Tags: modulation, bpsk

I know this is a programming question but i am trying to understand the logic of this. I have come across below function which is basically written in the `groovy`, which i think is BPSK modulation function.

```
private final int SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL = 150
private final float NFREQ = 1/15

private float[] bytes2signal(byte[] buf) {
  float[] signal = new float[buf.length * 8 * SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL * 2]   // 8 bits/byte, 2 floats/sample
  int p = 0
  for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {         // Not sure what is the significant of this ?
      int bit = (buf[i] >> j) & 0x01      // Not sure what is the significant of this ?
      float f = bit == 1 ? -NFREQ : NFREQ 
      for (int k = 0; k < SAMPLES_PER_SYMBOL; k++) {
        signal[p++] = (float)Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * f * k)
        signal[p++] = (float)Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * f * k)
      }
    }
  }
  return signal
}
```

My question is what is significant of this two lines?

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {         // Not sure what is the significant of this ?
    int bit = (buf[i] >> j) & 0x01     // Not sure what is the significant of this ?
```

Can someone please explain this to me ? What is logically happening with this buffer shifting by 8 bit and And-ing with 0x01. Below is the test function for iteration i=0

```
------------------------------------------------------------
i = 0
j = 0
1 >> 0 = 1
1 & 0x01 = 1
f = -0.06666666666666667
------------------------------
j = 1
1 >> 1 = 0
0 & 0x01 = 0
f = 0.06666666666666667
------------------------------
j = 2
1 >> 2 = 0
0 & 0x01 = 0
f = 0.06666666666666667
------------------------------
j = 3
1 >> 3 = 0
0 & 0x01 = 0
f = 0.06666666666666667
------------------------------
j = 4
1 >> 4 = 0
0 & 0x01 = 0
f = 0.06666666666666667
------------------------------
j = 5
1 >> 5 = 0
0 & 0x01 = 0
f = 0.06666666666666667
------------------------------
j = 6
1 >> 6 = 0
0 & 0x01 = 0
f = 0.06666666666666667
------------------------------
j = 7
1 >> 7 = 0
0 & 0x01 = 0
f = 0.06666666666666667
------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: this is a "how does groovy work" question, not really signal processing, is it? I mean, that first line is a `for` loop. That's a concept you'll find in any modern imperative language. I guess you know what it does (if not, learn the basics of groovy); the other is a simple bit operation, and that's also quite basically two core operators of groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what is significant of this two lines

The code receives a buffer of bytes but the modulation is based on a stream of bits. The outer loop loops over all bytes in the buffer. The

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
```

This loops over all 8 bits in the current byte

```
int bit = (buf[i] >> j) & 0x01
```

This tests whether the j'th bit in the current byte is 1 on 0, where j = 0 produces the LSb and j = 7 produces the MSb.

If your current byte is 0b11001001, then the variable "bit" will be 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 in each of the 8 loop iterations. Depending whether the current bit is 1 or 0, the modulated signal is generated in phase or out of phase.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i want to know.